# Who can tell me that how could it get the value of register DS

Tags: c, ucos

In the source of uc/os, I couldn't understand the following code.

***stk   = _DS;**

It's comments is to  get current value of DS.

Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost certainly, the compiler recognises `_DS` as a special "variable" and, instead of extracting the contents of that variable from wherever variables are stored, it just uses the contents of the data segment register directly.

In other words, `a = b` might be compiled as:

```
mov  ax, [0x12341234] // assuming b is at this location.
mov  [0x56785678], ax // assuming a is at this location.
```

whereas `a = _DS` may be:

```
push ds               // or, if available: mov ax, ds
pop ax
mov  [0x56785678], ax // assuming a is at this location.
```

Comment: yeah,with your examples,I think that I'v got the answer.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's a compiler defined macro (I assume this due to the upper case only name). The leading `_` usually tells you it being compiler specific. So once the preprocessor runs it will insert its own code that will essentially return the current value of DS.